# How to remove a sub string pattern from a json string in vim?

Tags: vim

```
json_str = {"type":"0","num":"1","processtime_ms":"14","model":"label"}
```

I have a lot of json string like this, and I want to remove this part from the string in vim:

```
"processtime_ms":"14",
```

I know how to remove a full line when matching a pattern, but how to remove the substring?

Comment: I tried this, but the match faied: %s/"processtime_ms":\d\+",//g

Comment: In you failed match, `%s/"processtime_ms":\d\+",//g` it looks like you left out a quotation mark.  Probably this would work?  `%s/"processtime_ms":"\d\+",//g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:1,$s/"processtime_ms":"14",//g
```

will remove the pattern from every line in the file

Comment: '14' can be any other digits, one or more

Comment: Then replace `14` with `\d+`.